# pandas printing maximum value found in a column with an f string

Tags: python, pandas, string-formatting

If I have some made up data... How do I print just the index (date & time stamp) of the maximum value found in a column named `Temperature`?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
np.random.seed(11)

rows,cols = 50000,2
data = np.random.rand(rows,cols) 
tidx = pd.date_range('2019-01-01', periods=rows, freq='H') 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Temperature','Value'], index=tidx)

maxy = df.Temperature.max()
maxDate = df.loc[df['Temperature'].idxmax()]
```

If I print `maxDate` there is alot of unwanted info..

```
print(maxy)
print(maxDate)
```

This outputs:

```
0.9999949674183947
Temperature    0.999995
Value          0.518413
Name: 2023-01-06 02:00:00, dtype: float64
```

Ultimately I am hoping to create an `f` string that just prints `maximum temperature recorded in the dataset is 0.999995 found on 2023-01-06 02:00:00`, Without the extra information such as `Name:` and `, dtype: float64` and the `Value          0.518413` column... Thanks for any tips & tricks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You f string could be:

```
f'maximum temperature recoded in the dataset is {maxy} found on {maxDate.name}'
```

Or without `maxy`:

```
f'maximum temperature recoded in the dataset is {maxDate.Temperature} found on {maxDate.name}'
```

Output:

```
'maximum temperature recoded in the dataset is 0.9999949674183947 found on 2023-01-06 02:00:00'
```

Answer (score 0):

There can be more than 1 entry with the maximum temperature.

```py
maxy = df.Temperature.max()
max_dates = df[df['Temperature'] == maxy].index.astype(str).to_list()
print(f'Max temperature recorded in dataset is {maxy} on {",".join(max_dates)}')
```

Output:

```
Max temperature recorded in dataset is 0.9999949674183947 on 2023-01-06 02:00:00
```